# Return Duration and turn it into a variable with Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, variables, google-maps-api-3

I want to put the duration, presented by google maps, into a variable (for example variable dur). The text now appears on the html directly. I want it to be in e.g. dur="21930 seconds" How has this to be done?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Complex</title> 
   <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head> 
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: red;"> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 
   <div id="duration">Duration: </div> 
   <div id="distance">Distance: </div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   var Anfang=new google.maps.LatLng(48.158572777778, 11.581866944444);
   var Ende= new google.maps.LatLng(48.22, 11.22);

   console.log(Anfang);

   var request = {
       origin:  Anfang,
       destination: Ende,
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
   };

   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

         // Display the distance:
         document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += 
            response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;

         // Display the duration:
         document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML += 
            response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;

      }
   });
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<table class="table table-condensed" border="1" id="usertable"></table>
<script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> BMW 1er
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> MINI Cooper
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> BMW ActiveE
  </label>
</div>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function callJSON() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
            $ ("#usertable").empty();
            //$data.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(b.fuelState) - parseFloat(a.fuelState) } );
            var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
            $.each(cars, function(key, data){
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                var Anfang=new google.maps.LatLng(48.158572777778, 11.581866944444);
                var Ende= new google.maps.LatLng(data.position.latitude, data.position.longitude);
                var request = {
                origin:  Anfang,
                destination: Ende,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING};
                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                var dur = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;}});
                var laenge=cars.length;
                var vint=data.vin;
                var coopers="";
                var tanken="";
                var drive="MAN";
                var fuelfarbe="#01DF3A";
                var prozent="%";
                var kosten=" 31 Cent/Min "
                var tanksymbol="glyphicon-tint";
                var farbe="success";
                var flugbadge="";
                var ortbadge="glyphicon-map-marker";
                var v=vint.substring(3,7);
                if(v=="SX31"){coopers=" S";}
                if(v=="SW71"){coopers=" SD";}
                if(data.model=="BMW ActiveE "){tanksymbol="glyphicon-flash";}
                if(data.model=="BMW X1 "){kosten=" 34 Cent/Min ";}
                if(data.auto=="Y"){drive="AUT";}
                if((48.347910654607695 < data.position.latitude && data.position.latitude < 48.35988839686733)&&(11.781678199768066 < data.position.longitude && data.position.longitude < 11.792492866516113)){flugbadge="<span class='badge'>+12€</span>"; ortbadge="glyphicon-plane";}
                if(data.fuelState<=25){tanken="20 Freiminuten für Vollbetankung"; farbe="warning";}
                $('#usertable').append(
                    function() {
                        return "<tr class="+farbe+">"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> "+data.carName+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data.model+coopers+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+drive+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon "+tanksymbol+"'></span>" +data.fuelState+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data.licensePlate+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon "+ortbadge+"'></span> "+data.address+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon "+ortbadge+"'></span> "+dur+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-euro'></span>"+kosten+flugbadge+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+laenge+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><a href='https://de.drive-now.com/php/metropolis/vehicle_details?vin="+ data.vin +"'target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-success btn-xs' type='button'>Reservieren</button></a></td>"+

                                    //"<td><img src='"+data.model+"1.png'/></td>"+
                                "<tr>"; 
                    }
                );
            })
        }).always(callJSON);
    }, 2000);
    }
    $(callJSON);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var dur = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;`

Comment: pleas see my update. I want to use the variable dur further below. But then it sais "dur undefined" How do i make this variable public?

Comment: That's because it's asynchronous, so you **can't** use it "further below" unless you wait for the async call to finish,

Comment: so its not possible to use the variable dur in my table? console.log(dur) is effective so far ..

Comment: As long as it's inside the callback of the ajax call, yes you can, but not outside it.

Comment: The table is inside of the ajax call or am i wrong?

Comment: It sure looks that way ?

Comment: Sorry iam a bloddy beginner .. :) .. so theres no chance?

Comment: Looking at it closer, `directionsService.route()` is also an async call, so you can't use the variable outside that either.

Comment: So theres no chance to implement the duration in my table?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BZGPA/1/

Comment: Thank you :) ... but now the variable dur is empty, when implemented in my table